# Count the lines of a PRE element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I count how many lines of text a `<pre>` tag contains?

I want to append a absolute div with line numbers next to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use the javascript split function to count the line breaks.

```
$('pre').html().split(/\n/).length
```

better

```
$('pre').html().match(/\n/)
```

Comment: You still need `.length` with match.  Also, note that you will want to add 1 to your match result, as you are counting line breaks.  See my answer for an example.

Comment: Fails if there is a <br> in the lines, better to use innerHTML and: /\n|<br>/ The line count seems to be out by one.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery

```
$('#preID').text().split('\n').length
```

using plain javascript

```
document.getElementById('preID').innerHTML.split('\n').length
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/tdekQ/

Answer (score 1):

This will work as long as you don't have any `<br>` tags in your `<pre>` element:

`var numlines = $('#mypreelement').text().match(/\n\r?/g).length + 1;`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/3QThm/

You can handle the `<br>` tags by counting them separately:

```
var pretext = $('#mypreelement').html();
var numlines = pretext.match(/\n\r?/g).length + 1;
numlines += $('#test br').length;
```

**Example:**  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/3QThm/2/

Other tags in the `<pre>` will cause you headaches.